# Xcode static libraries: Where are the symbols?

Tags: ios, macos, debugging, ld, dwarf

We have a rather large (and old) project, and we need to debug into a C++ function in a library that has not been touched for ages (64 Bit requirements you ask? How did you guess!)

But all we get is assembly code at that point.

It is further complicated by the fact that the library in question is build by some ancient CMake wizzardry.

My current main question is: if dsymutil --symtab does not list anything, does that mean there is no debug information in the .a file? 
Or is there another, foolproof way to find out if DWARF debugging information has actually been generated?

I am asking, because on a sample project for a static lib I created, I see a symtab in the .o files, but not in the resulting .a file.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that dsymutil does not work well (or at all) with static libraries.

Using ar -x to extract the .o files and then using dsymutil on them appears to work, and thus solve my issue